# How to pre-fill a type="url" form field with "http://" using html or php?

Tags: php, html, forms

**Problem**: on a form asking for the user's website, a type="url" form field returns an error unless "http://" precedes the domain name (there's even an error with "www.").

**Outcome I am seeking**: a PHP/HTML* method of partly pre-filling the type="url" field with "http://" so it's more user-friendly for users to type "companywebsite.com" into the field and submit without the error.

In other words, a user just fills in companywebsite.com and I want to pre-fill that with http:// so the end result is `http://companywebsite.com`

```
<h5>Website</h5>
<input type="url" name="company_website" id="company_website" value="" />
```

Image below is a screenshot of a form entry that has returned an error (because "http://" does not precede the stackoverflow.com domain).

[image: image of form error because "http://" wasn't in front of link]

** I did find a .js method (https://gist.github.com/cvan/117bc1f88e4dfca6dba7) but I'm a novice and just learning php*

Comment: Did you try `value="https://www.stackoverflow.com"`? I mean, that's as basic as you can get.

Comment: What's your debugging say?

Comment: @icecub, The form entry will vary from one user to the next - "stackoverflow.com" is an example of what is not working (there's no "http://" in front

Comment: @J.Han there is nothing to de-bug. The current code is 100% correct - I'm just looking for a way to make the form more user-friendly

Comment: So be more clear about your question. What is it that you want? You want `http://` to be prefilled in the form? Do you want to add it to string after the users submits the form? Please clerify

Comment: Have you tried `value="<?php echo "http://www." ?>" />`? Or just `value="http://www." />`?

Comment: Yes @icecub, you are correct in re-stating my question. Thanks.

Comment: It's still not clear enough. What exactly is happening right now? Basicly a user just fills in `google.com` and you want to prefill that with `http://` so the end result is `http://google.com`. Is that it?

Comment: I think this is what he wants to happen. `<input type="url" name="company_website" id="company_website" value="http://" />`

Comment: Yes @icecub, that's right.

Comment: I wouldn't use that as an aswer. It works, yes, but there are so many things that can go wrong with that! What if the user types a different string? Rule number 1 on the web: Never ever trust user input!

Comment: I agree with @icecub. Never ever trust user input. I would just do it as php code that adds it on at the beginning if it's not there.

Comment: Exactly @J.Han Use regex, verify input, modify string if needed, return errors.

Comment: Whoops, @J.Han's first idea `value="<?php echo "http://www." ?>"` pre-fills  http:// into the form, but I completed the form field after that with cisco.com and that field is empty in the database

Comment: What kind of method are you submitting the form?

Comment: Post your html form and your php part that handles it please. That'll allow us to actually give you a good answer instead of all this guessing.

Comment: What exactly is the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Don't bother @Valkyrie It's one of those "I got it working so I no longer care". Untill someone screws up his website, even though we warned him about that, he'll come back over here and expect us to solve it for him. Well, should've listened to us in the first place. - Perhaps I'm being an ass for saying this, but sometimes the truth must be told.

Comment: Actually @icecub (and @Valkyrie), I hadn't realized the time and had to run to a commitment, then time with my family, then sleep.

Comment: @J.Han's second idea above works perfectly (question is still on hold, even though I edited for clarity). Here's the code that works:  `<input type="url" name="company_website" id="company_website" value="http://" />`

Comment: I had another solution for you. I posted in the answer but deleted it because I thought it might be too difficult for you since you're a beginner.

Comment: Alright. In that case I appologise for my outburst. I've given you an answer that will hopefully teach you quite a bit. You don't have to change it as the accepted answer. I'm not here to take anything away from @J.Han Just to teach you something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could go about this:

```
<input type="url" name="company_website" id="company_website" value="http://" />
```

However, I would advise against this because you can never trust the user to input correctly. Instead, assuming you are submitting your form via the POST method, in your php code,

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['company_website'])){
        $pos = strpos($_POST['company_website'], "http://");
        if($pos != 0){
            $website = "http://".$_POST['company_website'];
        }
        // do the rest
    }
?>
```

Comment: I suggest holding back with your answer untill he posts his code. It's not wrong, but as a beginner, he most likely has no idea how to implement any of this in his own code.

Comment: I'll delete it for now then.

Comment: Thank you @J.Han and @icecub. I used the first (simpler) option to get it working and will try the 2nd option later.  I added placeholder text, in case the user deletes the pre-filled '"http://"' - here's the final line of code: `<input type="url" name="company_website" id="company_website" value="http://" placeholder="http://yourdomain.com" />`  Here's an image of the outcomes: http://enlightenedjobs.com/images/success-all.png (feel free to add image to your answer, since I can't upload it to a comment)

Answer (score 1):

Well then. For the purpose of learning something about security, I'll write this answer with some example code, so you know how to do this kind of stuff safely in the future.

First, lets write a small form:

```
<form method="POST" action="your_php_file.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="url" name="company_website" id="company_website" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Update website" />
</form>
```

Now lets start writing our PHP file based on this. First we need to be sure the user is submitting new data and not an empty string:

```
if(isset($_POST['company_website']) && !empty($_POST['company_website'])){
```

Next we'll write a function that checks if the string is a website or not:

```
function isWebsite($url){
```

To see if a string matches a website, we'll be using regular expressions. Regex can be quite complicated, so at the end of this answer, I'll post a link to learn more about them.

```
    $pattern = '#((https?|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))([\s)\[\]{},;"\':<]|\.\s|$)#i';
```

Now lets write a simple if statement that returns us true or false. To keep it simple, this statement compares the variable `$url` (which contains the user data) with the above regular expression pattern in `$pattern`. It will return true if `$url` contains a valid website, or false if it doesn't.

```
    if(preg_match($pattern, $url)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Next we'll write a function that adds 'http://' in front of the data send by the user:

```
function addHttp($url){
    $url = "http://". $url;
    return $url;
}
```

Now that our functions are complete, all we have to do is use them. First we'll check if the user already sent a valid website:

```
if(isWebsite($_POST['company_website'])){
    //The website is valid, so you can safely add it your database here
    } else {
        //The website is not valid, but the user might simply have forgotten
        //to add http:// in front of it. So lets do it for him:
        $website = addHttp($_POST['company_website']);

        //Still we can't be sure if it's a valid website. It might be a string
        //that will try to mess with your database. So lets verify it again:
        if(isWebsite($website)){
            //The website is now valid, so you can safely add it your database here
        } else {
            //The website is still not valid, so we need to return an error
            //to your user:
            echo "It seems you didn't enter a valid website. Please try again!";
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

As you might have noticed, we have 2 places in our code where we need to write the same code to insert everything in the database. You could use a function for that as well:

```
function addToDatabase($url){
    //Write your code to add everything to database here. $url will contain the website
}
```

So the complete code would become as follows:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['company_website']) && !empty($_POST['company_website'])){

    function isWebsite($url){
        $pattern = '#((https?|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))([\s)\[\]{},;"\':<]|\.\s|$)#i';

        if(preg_match($pattern, $url)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function addHttp($url){
        $url = "http://". $url;
        return $url;
    }

    function addToDatabase($url){
        //Write your code to add everything to database here. $url will contain the website
    }

    if(isWebsite($_POST['company_website'])){
        addToDatabase($_POST['company_website']);
    } else {
        //The website is not valid, try adding 'http://'
        $website = addHttp($_POST['company_website']);

        if(isWebsite($website)){
            addToDatabase($website);
        } else {
            //The website is still not valid, return error
            echo "It seems you didn't enter a valid website. Please try again!";
            exit;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I should add that it still might not be safe to just blindly add the website to your database. To make it absolutely secure, you'll need to use [PDO()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) in combination with Prepared Statements. But explaining that in this answer would turn this into a book. So make sure to learn about it!

Lastly I promissed to give a resource to learn more about Regular Expressions. The best and safest resource would be from the official PHP website itself. You can find it here: [PHP: Pattern Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Comment: I finally started going through @icecub's tutorial (which I'm grateful for) and noticed `accept-charset="utf-8"` in the first line creating the form. Trying to learn more, I found this page (http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html) saying "Some rules of thumb when dealing with Unicode text:

    Do not EVER use functions that:
        ...convert case (strtolower, strtoupper, ucfirst, ucwords)
        ...claim to be case-insensitive (str_ireplace, stristr, strcasecmp)
    Think twice before using functions that..." Am I opening a can of worms with `accept-charset="utf-8"`???

Comment: @MarkGavagan No. `accept-charset="utf-8"` only means the form will encode the characters to UTF-8 when it's send. This can be usefull when dealing with visitors on your website that send strange characters through your form. Like Chinese characters for example. I've personally experienced cases where Javascript, websockets etc crash because of non-utf8 characters being submitted by users. Those warnings are about messing around with the characters in the backend.

Comment: @MarkGavagan If you verify the characters in the backend with regex, like I did in `function isWebsite()`, you can make sure they're valid ASCII characters. After which it'll be fine to use those specific PHP functions on it if you require them.